# Add touch in UIView - Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I got this example from the Xamarin web site...for some reason, this is not working...

```
private UIView buildPage(Page p) {
    var v = new UIView();
    v.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
    var img = UIImage.FromFile("pages/" +p.filename + ".png");
    UIImageView imgView = new UIImageView(new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, vpWidth, vpHeight));
    imgView.Image = img;
    imgView.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit;
    v.Add(imgView);
    for (int e = 0; e < p.elements.Count; e++) {
        if (p.elements[e].type == "pageReplace") { 
            UIImageView link = new UIImageView(new CoreGraphics.CGRect(p.elements[e].left, p.elements[e].top, p.elements[e].width, p.elements[e].height));
            if (debug) {
                link.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green;
                link.Alpha = 0.5f;
            }
            link.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
            UITapGestureRecognizer tapGesture = new UITapGestureRecognizer(tst);
            link.AddGestureRecognizer(tapGesture);
            v.Add(link);
        }
    }
    return v;
}
public void tst() {
    Console.WriteLine("dswwwww");
}
```

What could be wrong ?
This function can put the view named link (in green), but when I click on it..nothing happens.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see a couple of issues:

1. you are not adding the first view you create, `v`, to any superview so it will not be onscreen.
2. You have not set a position/size for the first view, `v`.

So trying your code above in a new Xam.iOS project and adding the code to the `ViewController`'s `ViewDidLoad` method with the above issues fixed, the following worked as expected:

```
 UIView v = new UIView(new CoreGraphics.CGRect(20, 20, View.Frame.Width-40, View.Frame.Height-40)); // Give the first view a position/size

 v.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Gray; // Make it easy to see

 UIView link = new UIView(new CoreGraphics.CGRect(100, 100, 100, 100));

 //link.UserInteractionEnabled = true; // Not needed.

 link.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green; // Make it easy to see what to click on

 UITapGestureRecognizer tapGesture = new UITapGestureRecognizer(tst);

 link.AddGestureRecognizer(tapGesture);

 v.Add(link);

 View.Add(v); // View is the main view of the ViewController by default.
```

Now clicking on the green box triggers the `tst()` method as expected. However there is no need for the `v` view here, so the following would work fine as well:

```
 UIView link = new UIView(new CoreGraphics.CGRect(100, 100, 100, 100));

 link.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green; 

 UITapGestureRecognizer tapGesture = new UITapGestureRecognizer(tst);

 link.AddGestureRecognizer(tapGesture);

 View.Add(link);
```

Do you have a link to the document that the code came from? I am curious to see the context and how they got away with not adding the `v` view to the hierarchy. Also as I am a Xamarin support engineer, if there is an error in the docs I would like to get them fixed.

Comment: It's because I just put the piece of code that could be relevant...But I just edited it and put everything now. I'm adding to the super view. Check the code and the result now. It's basically a function that's returns a UIView. ty !

Comment: Page p = getPage(s);
   UIView st = buildPage(p);
   mainContainer.Subviews[curPage].AddSubview(st);
   this.View.Add(mainContainer);

Comment: I think U have everything now :) thanks for your attention. I'm actually learning Xamarin. I came from Appcelerator.

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating a widget or an apple watch extension? `Console.WriteLine()` won't work on those.

Comment: It's just a simple iPad application. I used to use Console.Writeline in many occasions.